# Next [target] for the burnination posse

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/target) is a completely ambiguous tag. According to the tag wiki this was supposedly meant to be related to make files. But the current tag usage is incredibly broad, containing everything from HTML to microcontroller flash programming.

The tag isn't helpful for searching, categorizing or anything else.

Can we please burninate this one?

Comment: In the times of llvm, target raises importance. Maybe specialise is, e.g. `make-target`, `llvm-target`, etc....?

Comment: @Matthias Yes there might need to be more specialized tags such as the ones you propose. [These posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile+target) could all use a tag [make-target] instead.

Comment: Really? What is the need when we already have [tag:make]?

Comment: We found a witch/bad tag! May we burniate it?